# Changing code from Sequential Consistency to a less stringent ordering in a barrier implementation

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic, barrier

I came across this code for a simple implementation of a barrier (for code that can't use `std::experimental::barrier` in C++17 or `std::barrier` in C++20) in C++ Concurrency in Action book.

[Edit]
A barrier is a synchronization mechanism where a group of threads (the number of threads is passed to the constructor of the barrier) can arrive at and wait (by calling wait method) or arrive at and drop off (by calling done_waiting). If all the threads in the group arrive at the barrier, then the barrier is reset and the threads can proceed with the next set of actions. If some threads in the group drops off, then the number of threads in the group is reduced accordingly for thenext round of synchronization with the barrier.
[End of Edit]

Here is the code provided for a simple implementation of a barrier.

```
struct barrier
{
   std::atomic<unsigned> count;
   std::atomic<unsigned> spaces;
   std::atomic<unsigned> generation;
   barrier(unsigned count_):count(count_),spaces(count_),generation(0)
   {}
   void wait(){
      unsigned const gen=generation.load();
      if(!--spaces){
         spaces=count.load();
         ++generation;
      }else{
         while(generation.load()==gen){
            std::this_thread::yield();
         }
      }
   }
   void done_waiting(){
      --count;
      if(!--spaces){
         spaces=count.load();
         ++generation;
      }
   }
};
```

The author, Anthony Williams, mentions that he chose sequential consistency ordering to make it easier to reason about the code and said that relaxed ordering could be used to make the code more efficient. This is how I changed the code to employ relaxed ordering. Please help me understand if my code is right.

```
struct barrier
{
   std::atomic<unsigned> count;
   std::atomic<unsigned> spaces;
   std::atomic<unsigned> generation;
   barrier(unsigned count_):count(count_),spaces(count_),generation(0)
   {}
   void wait(){
      unsigned const gen=generation.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
      if(1 == spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)){
         spaces=count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
         generation.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
      }else{
         while(generation.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)==gen){
            std::this_thread::yield();
         }
      }
   }
   void done_waiting(){
      count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if(1 == spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)){
         spaces=count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
         generation.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
      }
   }
};
```

The reasoning is this. The increment of generation is a release operation that synchronizes with the loading of generation in the wait call. This ensures that the load from count into spaces is visible to all the threads that call wait and read the new value of generation that was stored with release semantics.

All the operations on spaces thereafter are RMW operations which take part in a release sequence and hence can be relaxed operations. Is this reasoning correct or is this code wrong? Please help me understand. Thanks in advance.

[Edit]I tried using my barrier code like this.

```
void fun(barrier* b){
        std::cout << "In Thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
        b->wait();
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " First wait done" << std::endl;
        b->wait();
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " Second wait done" << std::endl;
        b->done_waiting();
}

int main(){
        barrier b{2};
        std::thread t(fun, &b);
        fun(&b);
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " <<  b.get_count() << std::endl;
        t.join();
}
```

I also tried testing it with many more threads and in superficial runs, it seems to be doing the right thing. But I would still like to understand if my reasoning is correct or if I am missing something very obvious.[End of Edit]

Comment: Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can someone please give me just one upvote so that I will have the required 75 points to offer a bounty?

Comment: Alternatively, you can answer questions to earn the upvote. (Sorry, I already gave you my vote.) ;-) Additionally, 2 points can be earned quite easy with fixing questions (fixing formatting, improving wording, etc.)

Comment: Haha. True that. Will try doing the same.

Comment: A release sequence has to be a sequence of side effects *on the same object*, of which the first one is release and the rest are RMW.  Currently you never perform any release stores to `spaces`, so none of your `spaces.fetch_sub()` can be part of any release sequence.  Nor would it help if they were, because you don't do any acquire loads of `spaces` to be synchronized with.

Comment: Thanks again Nate. I realized that I had to offer the bounty separately (I thought accepting the answer would offer the bounty immediately). Sorry about the delay. Your answer was definitely worth more than the 50 points I was able to offer. Thanks again for taking the effort to answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Modified version of the code

I believe the following version of the code has the weakest orderings
that still make it correct.

```
struct barrier
{
   std::atomic<unsigned> count;
   std::atomic<unsigned> spaces;
   std::atomic<unsigned> generation;
   barrier(unsigned count_):count(count_),spaces(count_),generation(0)
   {}
   void wait(){
      unsigned const gen=generation.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if(1 == spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)){
         spaces.store(count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed),
                      std::memory_order_relaxed);
         generation.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
      }else{
         while(generation.load(std::memory_order_acquire)==gen){
            std::this_thread::yield();
         }
      }
   }
   void done_waiting(){
      count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
      if(1 == spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)){
         spaces.store(count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed), 
                      std::memory_order_relaxed);
         generation.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
      }
   }
};
```

### Discussion of new version

Throughout this discussion, when we speak of the "last" thread to reach the barrier in
a particular generation, we mean the unique thread that sees
`spaces.fetch_sub(1)` return the value 1.

In general, if a thread is making a store that promises some operation has
completed, it needs to be a release store.  When another thread loads
that value to get proof that the operation is complete, and it is safe
to use the results, then that load needs to be acquire.

Now in the code at hand, the way a thread indicates that it is done with its "regular
work" (whatever was sequenced before the call to `wait()` or
`done_waiting()`) is by decrementing `spaces`, i.e. storing a value
that is 1 less than the previous value in the modification order.  For
a non-last thread, that's the *only* store that it does.  So
that store, namely `spaces.fetch_sub()`, has to be release.

For the last thread, the way that it knows it is last is by loading
the value 1 in `spaces.fetch_sub()`.  This serves as proof that all
other threads have finished their regular work, and that the last
thread can safely drop the barrier.  So `spaces.fetch_sub()` needs to
be acquire as well.  Hence `spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel)`.

The way that the non-last threads determine that the barrier is down and
they can safely proceed is by loading a value from `generation` in
the yield loop, and observing that it is different from `gen`.  So
that load needs to be acquire; and the store it observes, namely
`generation.fetch_add()`, needs to be release.

I claim that's all the barriers we need.  The work done by the `last`
thread to update `spaces` from `count` is effectively in its own
little critical section, begun with the acquire load of 1 from
`spaces` and ended with the release increment of `generation`.  At
this point, all other threads have already loaded and stored `spaces`,
every thread that called `wait` has already loaded the old value of
`generation`, and every thread that called `done_waiting()` has
already stored its new decremented value for `count`.  So the last
thread can safely manipulate them with relaxed ordering, knowing that
no other thread will do so.

And now the initial load `gen = generation.load()` in `wait()` does *not*
need to be acquire.  It can't be pushed down past the store to
`spaces`, because the latter is release.  So it is sure to be safely
loaded before the value 1 is stored to `spaces`, and only after that
could a potential `last` thread update `generation`.

### A proof

Now let's try to give a formal proof that this new version is correct.  Look at two threads, A and B,
which do

```
barrier b(N); // N >= 2
void thrA() {
    work_A();
    b.wait(); // or b.done_waiting(), doesn't matter which 
}

void thrB() {
    b.wait();
    work_B();
}
```

There are `N-2` other threads, each of which calls either `b.wait()`
or `b.done_waiting()`.  For simplicity, let's suppose we begin at
generation 0.

We want to prove that `work_A()` happens before `work_B()`, so that
they can be operating on the same data (conflicting) without a data
race.  Consider two cases depending on whether or not B is the last
thread to reach the barrier.

Suppose B is the last thread.  That means it did an acquire load of the
value 1 from `spaces`.  Thread A must necessarily have release-stored some
value >= 1, which was then successively decremented by atomic RMW
operations (in other threads) until it reached 1.  That is a release
sequence headed by A's store, and B's load takes its value from the
last side effect in that sequence, so A's store synchronizes with B's
load.  By sequencing, `work_A()` happens before A's store, and B's
load happens before `work_B()`, hence `work_A()` happens before
`work_B()` as desired.

Now suppose B is not the last thread.  Then it returns from `wait()`
only when it loads from `generation` a value different from `gen`.
Let L denote the actual last thread, which could potentially be A.

I claim, as a first step, that `gen` in B must be 0.  For the load of
`generation` into `gen` happens before B's release store in `spaces.fetch_sub()`, and as noted above, this heads a release sequence which
eventually stores the value 1 (in the second-to-last thread).  The
load of `spaces` in L takes its value from that side effect, so B's
store to `spaces` synchronizes with L's load.  B's load of
`generation` happens before its store to `spaces`, and L's load of
`spaces` happens before its store (`fetch_add()`) to `generation`.  So
B's load of `generation` happens before L's store.  By read-write
coherence [intro.races p17], B's load of `generation` must *not* take its value from L's store, but instead from
some earlier value in the modification order.  This must
necessarily be 0 as there are no other modifications to `generation`.

(If we were working at generation G instead of 0, this would prove only that `gen <= G`.  But as I explain below, all these loads happen after the previous increment of `generation`, which is where the value G was stored.  So that proves the opposite inequality `gen >= G`.)

So B returns from `wait()` only when it loads 1 from `generation`.
Thus, that final acquire load has taken its value from the release
store to `generation` done by L, showing that L's store happens before
B's return.  Now L's load of 1 from `spaces` happens before its store
to `generation` (by sequencing), and A's store to `spaces` happens
before L's load of 1 as proved earlier.  (If L = A then the same
conclusion still holds, by sequencing.)  We now have the following
operations totally ordered by happens-before:

```
A: work_A();
A: store side of spaces.fetch_sub()
L: load of 1 in spaces.fetch_sub()
L: store side of generation.fetch_add()
B: acquire load of 1 from generation
B: work_B()
```

and have the desired conclusion by transitivity.  (If L=A then delete lines 2 and 3 above.)

We could similarly prove that all the decrements of `count` in the
various calls to `done_waiting()` happen before L's load of `count` to
store it into `spaces`, thus those can safely be relaxed.  The
re-initialization of `spaces` in L, and the increment of `generation`,
both happen before any thread returns from `wait()`, so even if those
are relaxed, any barrier operations sequenced afterwards will see the
barrier properly reset.

I think that covers all the desired semantics.

### Fences

We could actually weaken things a little more by using fences.  For
instance, the `acq` in `spaces.fetch_sub()` was solely for the benefit
of thread L which loads the value 1; other threads didn't need it.  So
we could do instead

```
if (1 == spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release)){
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    // ...
}
```

and then only thread L needs to pay the cost of the acquire.  Not that
it really matters much, since all other threads are going to sleep
anyway and so we're unlikely to care if they are slow.

### Data races in OP's original version

(This section was written earlier, before I made the modified version above.)

I believe there are at least two bugs.

Let's analyze `wait()` by itself.  Consider code that does:

```
int x = 0;
barrier b(2);

void thrA() {
    x = 1;
    b.wait();
}

void thrB() {
    b.wait();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

We wish to prove that `x = 1` in thrA **happens before** the evaluation of `x` in thrB, so that the code would have no data race and be forced to print the value `1`.

But I don't think we can.  Let's suppose thrB reaches the barrier first, which is to say that it observes `spaces.fetch_sub` returning 2.  So the loads and stores performed in each thread are sequenced as follows:

```
thrA:
x = 1;
gen=generation.load(std::memory_order_acquire);     // returns 0
spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);     // returns 1, stores 0
spaces=count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);       // stores 2
generation.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release); // returns 0, stores 1

thrB:
gen=generation.load(std::memory_order_acquire);     // returns 0
spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);     // returns 2, stores 1
generation.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);         // returns 0
... many iterations
generation.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);         // returns 1
x;                                                  // returns ??
```

To have any hope, we have to get some operation `A` in thrA to synchronize with some operation `B` in thrB.  This is only possible if `B` is an acquire operation that takes its value from a side effect in the release sequence headed by `A`.  But there is only one acquire operation in thrB, namely the initial `generation.load(std::memory_order_acquire)`.  And it does not take its value (namely `0`) from any of the operations in thrB, but from the initialization of `generation` that happened before either thread was started.  This side effect is not part of any useful release sequence, certainly not of any release sequence headed by an operation which happens after `x=1`.  So our attempt at a proof breaks down.

More informally, if we inspect the sequencing of `thrB`, we see that the evaluation of `x` could be reordered before any or all of the relaxed operations.  The fact that it's only evaluated conditionally on `generation.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` returning 1 doesn't help; we could have `x` loaded speculatively much earlier, and the value only used after `generation.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` finally returns 1.  So all we know is that `x` is evaluated sometime after `generation.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` returns 0, which gives us precisely no useful information at all about what thrA might or might not have done by then.

This particular issue could be fixed by upgrading the load of `generation` in the spin loop to acquire, or by placing an acquire fence after the loop exits but before `wait()` returns.

---

As for `done_waiting`, it seems problematic too.  If we have

```
void thrA() {
    x = 1;
    b.done_waiting();
}

void thrB() {
    b.wait();
    std::cout << x;
}
```

then presumably we again want `1` to be printed, without data races.  But suppose thrA reaches the barrier first.  Then all that it does is

```
x = 1;
count.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // irrelevant
spaces.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // returns 2, stores 1
```

with no release stores at all, so it cannot synchronize with thrB.

Informally, there is no barrier to prevent the store `x=1` from being delayed indefinitely, so there cannot be any guarantee that thrB will observe it.

It is late here, so for the moment I leave it as an exercise how to fix this.

---

By the way, ThreadSanitizer detects data races for both cases: https://godbolt.org/z/1MdbMbYob.  I probably should have tried that first, but initially it wasn't so clear to me what to actually test.

---

I am not sure at this point if these are the only bugs, or if there are more.

Comment: Thank you so much Nate. Your answer taught me so much. I now have a better understanding of what needs to be taken into consideration when facing issues like this. Thanks again.